# python gradient descent error when plotting map()

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-3.7

I tried to run the code below,

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import partial

def difference_quotient(f,x,h):
    return(f(x+h)-f(x))/h


def square(x):
    return x*x

def derivative(x):
    return 2*x


derivative_estimate = partial(difference_quotient,square,h=0.0001)
x = range(-10,10)
y = range(-10,10)
plt.title("actual vs estimation")
plt.plot(x,map(derivative,x),'rx',label="actual")
plt.plot(x,map(derivative_estimate,x),'b+',label="estimate")
plt.show()
print(len(list(map(derivative,x))))
```

but it shows error below

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\units.py", line 168, in
>   get_converter
>       if not np.all(xravel.mask): AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mask'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\asus\Documents\Sublime\dataScience\gradient.py", line 20, in
>   
>       plt.plot(x,map(derivative,x),'rx',label="actual")   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
>   line 2811, in plot
>       is not None else {}), **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib__init__.py", line 1810,
>   in inner
>       return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 1611,
>   in plot
>       for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 393,
>   in _grab_next_args
>       yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 370,
>   in _plot_args
>       x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 205,
>   in _xy_from_xy
>       by = self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1467, in
>   update_units
>       converter = munits.registry.get_converter(data)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\units.py", line 181, in
>   get_converter
>       converter = self.get_converter(next_item)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\units.py", line 187, in
>   get_converter
>       thisx = safe_first_element(x)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook__init__.py", line
>   1635, in safe_first_element
>       raise RuntimeError("matplotlib does not support generators " RuntimeError: matplotlib does not support generators as input
>   [Finished in 0.7s]

my suspect was on these line,

```
plt.plot(x,map(derivative,x),'rx',label="actual")
plt.plot(x,map(derivative_estimate,x),'b+',label="estimate")
```

when I tried to change the map(derivative,x) and map(derivative_estimate,x) with y which is range(-10,10), it works.

what should I do so the code can show the plot when I use the map function like above?

Comment: please place back the original traceback. Use >```python /n traceback text```

Answer (score 1):

> RuntimeError: matplotlib does not support generators as input

Means you cannot use put as argument something called a python [`generator`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)
You need to assign the real values of `map(derivative,x)` and `map(derivative_estimate,x)` to actual variables.

Try this:

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import partial

def difference_quotient(f,x,h):
    return(f(x+h)-f(x))/h


def square(x):
    return x*x

def derivative(x):
    return 2*x

derivative_estimate = partial(difference_quotient,square,h=0.0001)
x = range(-10,10)
y = range(-10,10)

a = map(derivative,x)
b = map(derivative_estimate,x)

plt.title("actual vs estimation")
plt.plot(x,a,'rx',label="actual")
plt.plot(x,b,'b+',label="estimate")
plt.show()
print(len(list(map(derivative,x))))
```

**However**, your code is working perfectly fine for me using `python 3.4.3` and `matplotlib==2.2.4`. What version are you using yourself?

Comment: the python I'm using is 3.7 and the matplotlib == 3.0.3

Comment: @AriyaSusanto did you try my proposition?

Comment: sorry for the late reply,
I did, but the solution you provided shows an error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\units.py", line 168, in get_converter
    if not np.all(xravel.mask):
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mask'

Answer (score 1):

You will need to turn the generator into a list of values. E.g. instead of `map(func, values)`, use `list(map(func, values))`. In your case:

```
plt.plot(x, list(map(derivative,x)), 'rx', label="actual")
plt.plot(x, list(map(derivative_estimate,x)), 'b+', label="estimate")
```